# Send different nibs in a function swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, xib

I have a tableView who need to contain two different view, the name of the first one is **CustomTableViewCell** the second one is **CustomDeliveryTableViewCell**
I want my variable to take the two cell, I don't understand this error.
[image]
Here my function

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell: UITableViewCell
    cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UITableViewCell

    if (!self.appReady)
    {
        return cell
    }
    let arrayOfCard = self.selectedCard(section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)
    let json:JSON = JSON(arrayOfCard)
    if (json[0]["cards"][indexPath.row]["category"] == "delivery")
    {
        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomDeliveryTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell
    }
    cell = fillCell(cell: cell, json: json, index: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
```

My fonction fillCell is prototype like that

> func fillCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, json:JSON, index:Int) ->
>   CustomTableViewCell

**Edit**

Here the code  of actual fillCell function

```
    func fillCell(cell: UITableViewCell, json:JSON, index:Int) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (json[0]["cards"][index]["category"] == "train")
    {
        if let type = json[0]["cards"][index]["category"] as JSON?
        {
            cell.labelType.text = type.string
        }
        if let departureStation = json[0]["cards"][index]["train"]["departure"]["station"] as JSON?
        {
            cell.labelDepartureStation.text = departureStation.string
        }
    // Do some code
    }
    else if (json[0]["cards"][index]["category"] == "delivery")
    {
        //Do some code
        return cell
    }
    else{
        //Do some code
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post actual code rather than (or in addition to) screen shots. Makes it easier for people to copy code into answers. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is quite confused. You might want to try and tidy it up a bit as it's not clear what you're trying to do. For example, instead of passing JSON everywhere, you should look at creating objects (structs / enums) _from_ the JSON when it's loaded. This will make it easier to see what's going on. Additionally, you don't need to return a value from `fillCell`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assignment creates a `cell` of type `CustomDeliveryTableViewCell`.

Within the `if` block you're trying to assign a `CustomTableViewCell` to the same variable. This will only work if `CustomTableViewCell` is a subclass of `CustomDeliveryTableViewCell`

When you call `fillCell(` it's expecting `CustomTableViewCell`, but `cell` is a `CustomDeliveryTableViewCell`

If you declare `var cell: UITableViewCell` then you can assign either type to it.

Comment: If I do that, I need to change the protoype of fillCell =>CustomTableViewCell will  become UITableViewCell.
And if i do that my function doesn't compile, **Value of type 'UITableViewCell has no member labelDepartureStation**
I understand the error but I don't know how I can fix it

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question? I don't want to have to type it all out into an answer!